# Bootstrap Dropdown menu shifting around and styling not appearing

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Only been coding for a few months so your help is appreciated :)

I designed a customer header with a logo floating left and a call to action (CTA) button floating right and I want to turn those into dropdown menus onclick. I'm borrowing Bootstrap's Dropdown component. I’ve encountered a few issues:

1. **How to open the dropdown below the button?**: I’ve turned the logo icon
   into a dropdown menu and all the links are appearing in the intended
   colors that Bootstrap has set as default.  When logo is clicked
   in Google Chrome, the menu appears directly below the icon (which is
   where I want it). BUT when logo is clicked in Mozilla, the
   dropdown menu opens to the left of the icon and shifts the icon
   over. I’ve tried the “pull-right” class but that doesn’t put the
   dropdown menu BELOW the icon but to the right of it. How do I create
   an “pull-below” class so to speak and make sure it works across
   browsers?
2. **How to duplicate that dropdown menu for another button in the same header?**:
   For the CTA button, I’ve applied the exact same div structure as the
   dropdown for the icon that’s floating left so in theory, it should
   work the same. However, the dropdown menu options don’t display unless I hover over
   the options. It looks like it is inheriting an attribute somewhere
   telling it to make the font color white and overriding Bootstrap’s
   attributes. The issue is that none of my classes have any “color:
   white/#ffffff” anywhere so I’m not sure where it is inheriting that
   attribute from.
3. For the CTA button, the dropdown menu also opens up to the left
   instead of at the bottom.  When I take my code and paste it outside
   of any parent divs (as a standalone), the menu also opens up left
   and shifts the button over to the right instead of opening towards
   the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <div id="header-left">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            <img src="" />
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div id="header-right">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Take Pledge
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#header-container {
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #231F20;
    height: 50px;
}

#header-wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1300px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#header-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#header-right {
    float: right;
   margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.dropup,
.dropdown {
  position: relative;

}

.dropdown-toggle {
  *margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.dropdown-toggle:active,
.open .dropdown-toggle {
  outline: 0;
}

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 4px solid red;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";

}

.dropdown .caret {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;

}

.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu .divider {
  *width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 1px;
  *margin: -5px 0 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus,
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a,
.dropdown-submenu:focus > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}

.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #0081c2;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0077b3));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0088cc, #0077b3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  outline: 0;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
}

.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
}

.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .disabled > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
```

Comment: The fiddle is broken for me.  Looks like some links to bootstrap are missing.  Also tons of extra `>` in the html

Comment: NuclearGhost - apologies- I thought jsfiddle would be an easier way to visualize it but I can't get it working. Relatively new to programming so apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56HDm/1/),
I've commented out some styles (max-width etc..)

Changes are

#### HTML

```
<div id="header-right" class="pull-right">
```

#### CSS

```
#header-container {
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #231F20;
    height: 50px;
}

#header-wrapper {
    /*margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    max-width: 1300px;*/
    overflow: visible;
}

#header-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

#header-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
}

.dropup,
.dropdown {
  position: relative;

}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  *border-right-width: 2px;
  *border-bottom-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;

}
```

Hope this helps